# How to select all text in input with Reactjs, when it focused?

Tags: javascript, select, input, reactjs

For example: [codepen](http://codepen.io/Enclave88/pen/YqNpog?editors=1010)

```
var InputBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <input className="mainInput" value='Some something'></input>
    )
  }
});
```

Answer (score 291, accepted):

## `Functional component`:

```
const handleFocus = (event) => event.target.select();
const Input = (props) => <input type="text" value="Some something" onFocus={handleFocus} />
```

---

## `ES6 class component`:

```
class Input extends React.Component {
    handleFocus = (event) => event.target.select();

    render() {
        return (
            <input type="text" value="Some something" onFocus={this.handleFocus} />
        );
    }
}
```

---

## `React.createClass`:

```
React.createClass({
    handleFocus: function(event) {
      event.target.select();
    },

    render: function() {
      return (
        <input type="text" value="Some something" onFocus={this.handleFocus} />
      );
    },
})
```

Comment: this works in pure function (no class), thx for this solution.

Comment: @TK123 [You should avoid arrow functions in your render methods](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-arrow-functions-and-bind-in-reacts-render-are-problematic-f1c08b060e36). It also violates [jsx-no-bind](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md) which is used by [eslint-config-airbnb](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/packages/eslint-config-airbnb) for example.

Comment: How do I get this working for a `disabled` textbox? https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/317733/

Comment: @RahulDesai Instead of `disabled`, use `readOnly`: https://jsfiddle.net/kxgsv678/

Comment: is It possible select only a part of the text?

Comment: @MatteoAngelotti It's not meant to do that, but there may be a workaround. [`The HTMLInputElement.select() method selects all the text in a <textarea> element or in an <input> element that includes a text field.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select)

Comment: on mobile this triggers the context menu. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @Angelotti, you can select a part of the text the following way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54417080/5506730

Answer (score 11):

Another Way Functional Component with useRefHook:

```
const inputEl = useRef(null);

function handleFocus() {
  inputEl.current.select();
}

<input
  type="number"
  value={quantity}
  ref={inputEl}
  onChange={e => setQuantityHandler(e.target.value)}
  onFocus={handleFocus}
/>
```

Comment: I don't understand why you need the ref? You will have the event object when triggering the onFocus event.

Answer (score 11):

let's add the simplest based on @dschu's answer:

```
...
<input type='text' value='Some something' onFocus={e => e.target.select()} />
...
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's the simplest and it's typescript friendly.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks, I appreciate it. I did it so:

```
var input = self.refs.value.getDOMNode();
            input.focus();
            input.setSelectionRange(0, input.value.length);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var InputBox = React.createClass({
  getInitialState(){
    return {
      text: ''
    };
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <input
        ref="input"
        className="mainInput"
        placeholder='Text'
        value={this.state.text}
        onChange={(e)=>{this.setState({text:e.target.value});}}
        onFocus={()=>{this.refs.input.select()}}
      />
    )
  }
});
```

You have to set ref on the input and when focused you have to use select().

Answer (score 1):

```
var React = require('react');

var Select = React.createClass({
    handleFocus: function(event) {
        event.target.select()
    },
    render: function() {
        <input type="text" onFocus={this.handleFocus} value={'all of this stuff'} />
    }
});

module.exports = Select;
```

Auto select all content in a input for a react class. The onFocus attribute on a input tag will call a function. OnFocus function has a parameter called event generated automatically. Like show above event.target.select() will set all the content of a input tag.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I wanted to select the text from the beginning after the input appeared in the modal:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    this.refs.copy.select();
},

<input ref='copy'
```