# Fable.React: select input text on focus

Tags: f#, fable-f#

I'm trying to select the text of an input field using Fable.React.
In js it can be done like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051883/how-to-select-all-text-in-input-with-reactjs-when-it-focused), but trying the same in Fable doesn't compile:

```
input [                         
        Type "text"
        OnFocus(fun e -> e.target.select())
      ]
```

How can I select the text in an input field when it is focused using Fable.React ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to cast event.target first:

```
OnFocus(fun e -> 
          let target = e.target :?> Browser.HTMLInputElement
          target.select()
        )
```