# How select part of text in a Textfield on onFocus event with material-UI in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, textfield

I have a modal form with  material -UI TextField in react app,  I have a default value, es. a file, and i would select only the name of the file no the extension when the element is load....

I did this code  inside the tag TextField:

```
<textField 
    value={value}
    fullWidth
    autoFocus
    onFocus={event => {
    event.target.select()}} />
```

but this will select all text inside the textField.
[image]
How can I select only a part of the text?
ex: if i have myfile.doc i would be selected only myfile
like this
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please attach MCVE code https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `var filename = 'myfile.doc'; var filename_without_extension = filename.split('.')[0];`

Comment: but i have to show the extension inside the textFiled bat not select...

Comment: I think I answered ***but this will select all text inside the textField. How can I select only a part of the text? ex: if i have myfile.doc i would be selected only myfile***. If you have any another problems please listen to @AlvinTheodora advice in the first comment, which basically means you have to improve/update your question, or post another one. 

Your current code does not give us enough info to be able to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting all text in HTML text input when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067469/selecting-all-text-in-html-text-input-when-clicked)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [setSelectionRange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange) in combination with the `lastIndexOf` method to find the position of the last `.`.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  handleFocus = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { target } = event;
    const extensionStarts = target.value.lastIndexOf('.');
    target.focus();
    target.setSelectionRange(0, extensionStarts);
  }
  
  render(){
    return (
      <input
        value={'myfile.doc'}
        onFocus={this.handleFocus}
      />
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: gazdagergo perfect thank you very much, that was exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

I would use a split and take the first entry of the array.

```js
text = "mydoc.doc";
console.log(text.split(".")[0]);
```

Comment: But with this i will have in my textField only the name of the file, i need to have all name so "mydoc.doc" but only the part of the string  mydoc it will be selected